# How can I flash ClockworkMod with Heimdall on Galaxy Mini?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-mini, heimdall

I tried to flash ClockworkMod with Heimdall on my Galaxy Mini by doing the following:

- I go into download mode
- Plug in my phone
- Go into the recovery image folder
- Run `heimdall flash --kernel zImage`

I get this error and my phone stays in download mode:

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...
ERROR: Setting up interface failed!
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

USB debugging mode is enabled of course and I'm on Ubuntu. How can I successfully flash ClockworkMod?

Comment: Try connecting your phone to the PC via USB after starting the Heimdal tool.

Comment: i tried it but it fails detecting the device btw is heimdall compatible with galaxy mini right ??

Comment: Sometimes this is a permissions issue. If the command works with `sudo` in front of it but not with your user account, you don't have the proper permissions to the device. I'm not sure Heimdall uses ADB permissions - the Heimdall webpage should have more details.

Comment: i have run it again with sudo but i get the same error as before

Comment: Does the computer recognize the phone at all?  What does `adb devices` terminal command return? (you may need to install Android SDK if you haven't already)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just a got an email from the Heimdall dev, he said it's not compatible with the Galaxy Mini.  Thanks guys for your replies.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for letting us know the answer though.

Comment: @roxan i can't now tomorow ill :D