# Clockworkmod error on Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 - Failed to send data

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to install Clockworkmod on my Galaxy S4 (GT-I9500), but I'm running into an issue when installing.

I'm following the steps laid out [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9500), and I then receive this error when running Heimdall to start the flashing process...

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
ERROR: Failed to send data!Releasing device interface...
```

I've tried on both Mac and Windows machines, but I keep getting the same error.

I'm kind of at the end of my rope here, I've tried everything I can think of, and have googled my butt off, but no luck. :/

What could be causing this, and how can I get past it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Heimdall compatible with the I9500? I know other users have had compatability issues. Contact the dev maybe? Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20820/how-can-i-flash-clockworkmod-with-heimdall-on-galaxy-mini?rq=1 Not the same device but could be the same issue. Why not use ODIN on a Windows PC and do it that way, definitely works, Heimdall is a nix version.

Comment: As far as I know it should be, according to that tutorial I was following. I've tried Odin, but I get the same issue, Odin doesn't pick up the device at all.